# primefaces - TreeTable resets input on collpase

Tags: primefaces, treetable

I've got a Primefaces's TreeTable with input fields that are bind to a managed bean that contains some default data for the TreeTable.

The problem I am facing is that when user expands a node, changes value in the child's inputtext and then collpases the parent, the value that user previously changed in the inputtext is reseted to the default value stored in the managed bean.

My problem is that I don't want the value to be reseted.

Step1 http://oi57.tinypic.com/6p59np.jpg

Step2 http://oi62.tinypic.com/11t5ppy.jpg

Step3 http://oi58.tinypic.com/153brxk.jpg

I am using Primefaces 4.

Could you help me with this?

Thank you

Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add simple:

```
<p:ajax event="change"/>
```

into the p:inputText in the TreeTable